# In ASP.NET MVC 5 Server.MapPath() returning path with double backslashes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, server.mappath

In ASP.NET MVC 5, `Server.MapPath()` returning path with double backslashes and image file adding to my physical project `"~/Images/"` folder.But it is not displaying in my solution explorer even after refresh.I have tried `Replace()` "\" with "/" but it doesn't works. unable to display images now.

My Images Folder path:`"~/Images"`
Image Path in Database saving as : `"D:\\ProjectName\\SolutionFolder\\Images\\Image1.jpg"`

Please help me out of this...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Why display image? When do you use it?

Comment: The problem is not the double backslashes, that's the inspector escaping strings for you. The problem is using absolute file paths on a web page, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show images in asp.net Razor view like this:

```
<img src="~/images/Image1.jpg" />
```

And there is no need to use disk location (`Server.MapPath()` will return disk location of a specific path and is very dangerous)

---

**UPDATE:**

This is a useful link from Asp.net site about how to use images:

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/9-working-with-images

Comment: Hi @Author if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.